# Set image to Itextsharp.text.cell throws an error

Tags: vb.net, itext

I have an issue when i set the image to the cell

```
Dim CellAux As PdfPCell
CellAux = New PdfPCell(Image.GetInstance("../../Common/Images/image_logo.gif"))
```

and throws the next error: `cant find path c:\windows\Common\Images\image_logo.gif`

Why is looking for the image there?

What can i do to search the image in the right directory?

Answer (score 1):

When you run an application, you always run it from a Working Directory. That's not necessarily the directory you expect. In any case, you're using a relative path in your code, and the absolute path will be constructed using that relative path in combination with your working directory. The result in this case is c:\windows\Common\Images\image_logo.gif